# New GPU is not displaying on the monitor

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

I tried to install a new GPU into my system, but nothing displays on the monitor, and on the motherboard the VGA-LED is lit red.

I checked all the PCIe connections. I put my old GeForce GTX 560 Ti GPU back in and had no problems, but the new GPU won't post anything.

My System:

· MB: Asus M5A97
  CPU: AMD Phenom II X6
  PSU: Corsair TX650, 650 Watts
  RAM: Kingston 8GB
  GPU: Sapphire Radeon RX 590

Comment: What’s the old graphics card? // Did you connect all power connectors on the new graphics card?

Comment: The old graphics card is a Geforce GTX 560TI, and yeah I checked all the PCIE connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your BIOS. Asus LIVE UPDATE utility should help. I had the same problem, and updating my BIOS helped.